# What could make upload speeds vastly differ in CouchDB vs Apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, upload, couchdb

Imagine a server running CouchDB (on port 5984) and Apache (on port 80). Sending a 10MB POST to each servers yields wildly different results; it takes an average of 1-minute 30-seconds for POST'ing to CouchDB via Futon ('Upload attachment'), and only 15-seconds to POST to Apache.

What might cause this strange difference?

Comment: A bunch of questions before we can answer this:
- which connection is this on? localhost? lossy network? etc?
- which OS does CouchDB run on?
- what are your socket settings for CouchDB? Default or any edits?
- what, on the Apache end, is receiving the POST? A PHP script? mod_php, any other mod_*? Is it getting written to disk, etc. etc. :)

Comment: And which version of CouchDB?